# Array Declaration In Java through args[]

Tags: java, arrays

Im using NetBeans and im getting an error at that Line after compilation. Can anyone tell me why? I tried sending the values through command line arguments but it wouldnt work.

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[10];
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      a[i]=Integer.parseInt(args[i]); //Error in this Line
```

Comment: This `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)` should be `for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)`; otherwise, you must pass **exactly** ten arguments.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch It worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a = args.clone() to make them the exact same array (But seperate, instead of a = args which would just make "a" a Reference to args). Alternatively, Elliott's comment works.

You should also initialise it like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[args.length];
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    a = args.clone(); /*Does what you need by cloning the arguments array. Also takes up exactly as much room is needed to do so (I.e. Not always 10 spaces for values). */
```